# Rust: Understanding trait `From` implementation

Tags: rust

### How to understand trait FromWhatever in rust

The [Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html) explains following:

> The From trait allows for a type to define how to create itself from another type, hence providing a very simple mechanism for converting between several types.

Sounds simple enough. Lets try as simple example as possible:

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

struct MyStructure {}

// auto accepted suggestion from language server.
impl FromStr for MyStructure {
    type Err = (); // I've added this

    fn from_str(_s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Self {}) // I've added this
    }
}

fn main() {
    const INPUT: &str = "test";
    let _tmp: MyStructure = MyStructure::from(INPUT);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77485cf3bce6318840257e13ebafeee1)

```
Compiling test_range_2 v0.1.0 (/home/pavel/Repositories/test_range_2)
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/main.rs:15:47
    |
15  |     let _tmp: MyStructure = MyStructure::from(INPUT);
    |                             ----------------- ^^^^^ expected struct `MyStructure`, found `&str`
    |                             |
    |                             arguments to this function are incorrect
    |
note: associated function defined here
   --> /home/pavel/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/src/rust/library/core/src/convert/mod.rs:374:8
    |
374 |     fn from(_: T) -> Self;
    |        ^^^^

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0308`.
error: could not compile `test_range_2` due to previous error
```

So I expected this behavior:

```rust
let target: TARGET_TYPE = TARGET_TYPE::from::<SOURCE_TYPE>(input_var: SOURCE_TYPE);
```

Compared to the example in the [rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/conversion/from_into.html):

```rust
let num = Number::from(30);
```

It seems to me like a reasonable assumption.

However, reading the error message: "expected struct `MyStructure`, found `&str`". Does that mean that syntax is like this?

```rust
let target: TARGET_TYPE = TARGET_TYPE::from::<TARGET_TYPE>(input_var: TARGET_TYPE);
```

If, that's true, then code in the rust book should also fail with the error "expected `Number`, found `i32`", but it doesn't.

I expected my solution to work because I've implemented the `trait FromStr`, and I'm trying to create object from `&str` (see the "from" and "str"?). Which is also the type that was autocompleted by language server after I've typed `impl FromStr for MyStructure`. What am I missing? I want to impl FromStr for all my types but that compiler is not making it easy.

### Solution

```
use std::str::FromStr;

struct MyStructure {}

impl FromStr for MyStructure {
    type Err = ();

    fn from_str(_s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        Ok(Self {})
    }
}
impl From<&str> for MyStructure {
    fn from(_: &str) -> Self {
        Self {}
    }
}

fn main() {
    const INPUT: &str = "test";
    let _tmp0 = MyStructure::from_str(INPUT);
    let _tmp1 = MyStructure::from(INPUT);
}
```

I implemented `trait FromStr` but was referring to `trait From<&str>`. Since there is a trait in standard lib that looks like this:

```rust
trait From<T> -> T
```

compiler tried to use that in stead.

Comment: That page refers specifically to [`core::convert::From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/convert/trait.From.html). [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) is a different trait with different methods and expectations. They are not linked in such a way that would allow you to do `MyStructure::from(INPUT)`.

Comment: If you want to use `From`, why are you using `FromStr`?

Comment: @DanGetz ahh. Didn't notice that one. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) and [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) are completely different and entirely unrelated traits.

The first one performs 1 -> 1 infaillible conversions, while the latter is used to parse strings (it's a pretty old trait, its modern equivalent is [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) but because `FromStr` hooks into [`str::parse()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.parse) it remains convenient and popular).

Here you impl `FromStr`, which does nothing for your [`From::from`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html#tymethod.from) call.

Instead you get told about a blanket implementation: converting a type to itself is a no-op, so the standard library has

```
impl<T> From<T> for T
```

which just returns itself.

Hence the compiler's error message: when it encounters

```
MyStructure::from(INPUT);
```

and tries to resolve this to an implementation, the only `impl From<?> for MyStructure` it finds is the blanket implementation,

```
impl From<MyStructure> for MyStructure
```

and thus it tells you that it expects an argument of type `MyStructure` (the only possible input for the implementations it found), but found an `&str` (what you actually gave it).